# Store wdColor value as a variable

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a user form that allows me to enter a search term then (from a ComboBox) select a "color" from the dropdown. Drop down values are stored in the list as wdRed, wdBlue, wdYellow, etc. The goal is to highlight every instance of the search term with whatever color is chosen after clicking the command button named "Highlight_Widget".

The code within the command button in the form is:

```
Private Sub cmd_Run_Click()

Dim sFind As String
Dim sColor As String

Selection.HomeKey wdStory

sFind = Input_Search_Term.Value
sColor = Input_Color.Value

Debug.Print GetColorValue(sColor) ' for testing, and it prints the numeric color number

Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = GetColorValue(sColor)
    Selection.MoveRight
    Selection.Find.Execute
Loop

End Sub

Function GetColorValue(color As String) As Long
  Dim lngWdColor As Long

  Select Case color
     Case "wdRed"
        lngWdColor = 255
     Case "wdBrightGreen"
        lngWdColor = 65280
    Case "wdTurquoise"
        lngWdColor = 16776960
  End Select

  GetColorValue = lngWdColor

End Function



Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With Input_Color
        .AddItem "wdRed"
        .AddItem "wdBrightGreen"
        .AddItem "wdTurquoise"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Scolour is a string. WD Color enumerations are long inttegers which represent an RGB value . HighlightColorIndex is expecting a number which is probably from the wdcolorindex enumeration and not the wdcolor enumeraton.

Comment: I've just checked and wdRed is from the wdColorIndex enumeration.  wdColorRed is from the wdColor enumeration. wdColorRed has the value 255 (0x000000FF) whereas wdRed has the value 6.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm a novide but I think I understand what you're saying. How would I pass the255 value after someone selects "Red" from the combobox? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The `wd`-color name's are an enumeration, they're a "human-friendly" name for a `long` value. But they represent the `long` value and aren't a string. The drop-down `Value` returns a string, however, which is why there's a type mismatch.

What you can do is use `Select Case` to return a `long` from the `string`. Perhaps as a separate function. For example (you need to extend this example to use the colors you list):

```
Function GetColorValue(color as String) As Long
  Dim lngWdColor as long

  Select Case color
     Case "wdRed"
        lngWdColor = 6
     Case "wdGreen"
        lngWdColor = 11
  End Select
  GetColorValue = lngWdColor
End Function
```

And in the code in the question:

```
Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = GetColorValue(sColor)
```

Comment: Thank you Cindy - You have moved me closer!  I have edited my code in my original post to include the function you provided (and I tweaked ) but it still is not working for me. Not erroring like before...just not doing the highlighting.

Comment: @kroy2008 You're using the wrong values. You need to use the values I posted in my answer (for example). I do question, however, whether the loop will run at all since you don't `Execute` find once before `Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False`?

Comment: OK - for some reason I thought you had just put some example numbers in there so I pulled them from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdcolor. I think you'r eright about the "execute" issue - but I'm not sure where to put the command other than within the Do Loop. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @kroy2008  Put an `Execte` command just before the `Do`, as well.

Comment: @kroy2008 It looks like you took the values from wdColorIndex instead of wdColor?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is a common one in VBA because the language does not support reflection. This means that for enumerations we cannot say, for example.

wdTurquoise.ToString

and get a return value of the string "wdTurquoise".

This problem can be solved quite nicely by creating a new class which encapsulates the enumeration you are working with.  I use such classes quite a lot and I call them Reverse Lookup Enumeration Dictionaries.  I've created the class for managing wdColorIndex and the code is below.

The code requires that you go to Tools.References and tick the box for 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' because the class relies on the 'scripting.dictionary (a superior version of the VBA built in 'Collection').

Add a new class module and call it 'wdColorIndexGetsName'

Place the code below in the class.  There is quite a lot of code because it is based on a template that I have and introduces quite a lot of functionality other that value to name conversion.

```
Option Explicit

' This module requires Microsoft Scripting runtime
' See Tools.References and ensure that the box for
' 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' is ticked

Private Type properties
    value_gets_variant                           As Scripting.Dictionary
    variant_gets_value                           As Scripting.Dictionary

End Type

Private p                                       As properties

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set p.value_gets_variant = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set p.variant_gets_value = New Scripting.Dictionary

    With p.value_gets_variant

       .Add Key:=wdAuto, Item:="Automatic"                   ' 0
       .Add Key:=wdBlack, Item:="Black"                      ' 1
       .Add Key:=wdBlue, Item:="Blue"                        ' 2
       .Add Key:=wdBrightGreen, Item:="Bright green"         ' 4
       .Add Key:=wdByAuthor, Item:="User defined"            ' -1
       .Add Key:=wdDarkBlue, Item:="Dark blue"               ' 9
       .Add Key:=wdDarkRed, Item:="Dark red"                 ' 13
       .Add Key:=wdDarkYellow, Item:="Dark yellow"           ' 14
       .Add Key:=wdGray25, Item:="Gray 25"                   ' 16
       .Add Key:=wdGray50, Item:="Gray 50"                   ' 15
       .Add Key:=wdGreen, Item:="Green"                      ' 11
       ' Can't use wdNoHighlight as it has the same value as
       ' wdAutomatic
       '.Add Key:=wdNoHighlight, Item:="Remove highlight"     ' 0
       .Add Key:=wdPink, Item:="Pink"                        ' 5
       .Add Key:=wdRed, Item:="Red"                          ' 6
       .Add Key:=wdTeal, Item:="Teal"                        ' 10
       .Add Key:=wdTurquoise, Item:="Turquoise"              ' 3
       .Add Key:=wdViolet, Item:="Violet"                    ' 12
       .Add Key:=wdWhite, Item:="White"                      ' 8
       .Add Key:=wdYellow, Item:="Yellow"                    ' 7

    End With

    ' Now compile the reverse lookup
    Set p.variant_gets_value = ReverseDictionary(p.value_gets_variant, "wdColorIndexGetsName.variant_gets_value")

End Sub

Public Property Get Names() As Variant

    Set Names = p.value_gets_variant.Keys

End Property

Public Property Get Values() As Variant

    Set Values = p.value_gets_variant.Keys

End Property

Public Property Get Name(ByVal this_Value As WdColorIndex) As Variant

    Name = p.value_gets_variant.Item(this_Value)

End Property


Public Property Get Value(ByVal this_name As Variant) As WdColorIndex

    Value = p.variant_gets_value.Item(this_name)

End Property

Public Function HoldsValue(ByVal this_Value As WdColorIndex) As Boolean

    HoldsValue = p.value_gets_variant.Exists(this_Value)

End Function

Public Function LacksValue(ByVal this_Value As WdColorIndex) As Boolean

    LacksValue = Not Me.HoldsValue(this_Value)

End Function

Public Function HoldsName(ByVal this_name As Variant) As Boolean

    HoldsName = p.variant_gets_value.Exists(this_name)

End Function

Public Function LacksName(ByVal this_name As Variant) As Boolean

    LacksName = Not Me.HoldsName(this_name)

End Function

Public Function Count() As Long

    Count = p.value_gets_variant.Count

End Function

Public Function DicOfValueGetsName() As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set DicOfValueGetsName = p.value_gets_variant

End Function

Public Function DicOfNameGetsValue() As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set DicOfNameGetsValue = p.variant_gets_value

End Function

Private Function ReverseDictionary(ByRef this_dictionary As Scripting.Dictionary, Optional this_dictionary_name As String = vbNullString) As Scripting.Dictionary
' Swaps keys for Names in scripting.dictionaries.
' Keys and Names must be unique

    Dim my_key                                  As Variant
    Dim my_keys                                 As Variant
    Dim my_reversed_dictionary                  As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim my_message                              As String

    On Error GoTo key_is_not_unique
    Set my_reversed_dictionary = New Scripting.Dictionary
    my_keys = this_dictionary.Keys

    For Each my_key In my_keys
    Debug.Print this_dictionary.Item(my_key)
        my_reversed_dictionary.Add _
            Key:=this_dictionary.Item(my_key), _
            Item:=my_key

    Next

    Set ReverseDictionary = my_reversed_dictionary

    Exit Function

key_is_not_unique:

    On Error GoTo 0

    If Len(this_dictionary_name) = 0 Then
        my_message = vbNullString

    Else
        my_message = " in dictionary '" & this_dictionary_name & "' "

    End If

    my_message = "The key '" & my_key & "'is not a unique value" & my_message

    msgbox _
        Title:="Reverse Dictionary Error", _
        prompt:=my_message, _
        Buttons:=vbOKOnly

    Set ReverseDictionary = Nothing

End Function
```

Having done this you can now update your revised code to

```
Option Explicit

Public colors As New wdColourIndexGetsName

Private Sub cmd_Run_Click()

Dim sFind As String
Dim sColor As String

Selection.HomeKey wdStory

sFind = Input_Search_Term.Value
sColor = Input_Color.Value

Debug.Print GetColorValue(sColor) ' for testing, and it prints the numeric color number

Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = colors.Value(sColor)
    Selection.MoveRight
    Selection.Find.Execute
Loop

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
' Makes the assumption that Input_Color is a List box

    Input_Color.List = colors.Names

End Sub
```

This class nicely illustrates the advantage of OO code.  You code now no longer needs to know anything about what a colour is.

To get the name of a wdColorIndex enumeration you just use

```
this_colour_name = colors.Name(wdRed)
```

and vice versa

```
 this_colour_enum = colors.Value("Red")
```

The Names and Values properties return variant arrays of the string names of the colours and the enumeration values of the colours respectively.  This means that it is now easy to iterate over the enumeration or the string values.

```
Dim my_names() as variant
Dim my_name as variant

    my_names = colors.names
    For each my_name in my_names
        <other code>
    Next
```

If you have any question on the above code please message me, otherwise good luck with your endeavors.